# All goroutines are sleep deadlock

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine

Simulating my real problem I have this code.
Basically, each element of the array "letters" along with its index is sent to a goroutine to compare it with "x", then it sends a response through the channel.
My idea is that it runs on "x" threads, in the real case I use 8 threads.

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup
const sizeLetters = 12

func detectX(ch2 chan int, j int, letters [sizeLetters]string) {
    if letters[j] == "x" {
        ch2 <- j
    }else{
        ch2 <- -1
    }
}


func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int)
    ch2 := make(chan int)
    letters := [sizeLetters]string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"}
    threads:= 4
    wg.Add(threads)
    for i := 0; i < threads; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                j, ok := <-ch1
                if !ok {
                    wg.Done()
                }
                detectX(ch2, j, letters)
            }
        }()
    }
    for i := 0; i < sizeLetters; i++ {
        ch1<-i // add i to the queue
    }
    k, ok := <-ch2 //k contains the position of X, if exist
    if !ok {
        wg.Done()
    }
    if k != -1 { //when exist
        println("X exist in position: " + strconv.Itoa(k))
    }
    println("X doesn´t exist")
    close(ch2)
    close(ch1)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: `make(chan int)` creates a blocking channel. A write to it will only finish once it is matched with a concurrent read. When `detectX()` first writes to `ch2`, there is noone reading from it, because `main()` is still trying to push values into `ch1`. You are also trying to write 12 values into `ch2`, but only trying to read from it once.

Comment: @Zyl Which I would have to correct in my code, maybe with context, but I still don't know how to implement it very well. How would you send a response from detectX, when X is detected or not detected.

Comment: `context` exists for cancellation signals, so it makes sense here: you want work to stop when the result has been found. Also, I wouldn't write into ch2 unless you actually have a result. I'd also make ch2 buffered, i.e. use `make(chan int, 1)`. I'd also make `wg.Done()` called via `defer`. Right now you call `detectX()` even when you got no value from ch1. Then `wg.Wait()` after finishing writing to ch1 instead of at the end of `main()`. Maybe trying some simpler exercises will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insufficient reputation to comment. So, in lieu of a comment, here is an alternate version of the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

const sizeLetters = 12

func detectX(ch2 chan int, j int, letters [sizeLetters]string) {
    if letters[j] == "x" {
        ch2 <- j
    }
}

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int)
    ch2 := make(chan int)
    letters := [sizeLetters]string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"}
    threads := 4
    wg.Add(threads)
    for i := 0; i < threads; i++ {
        go func() {
            for {
                j, ok := <-ch1
                if !ok {
                    wg.Done()
                    return
                }
                detectX(ch2, j, letters)
            }
        }()
    }
    // Use a goroutine to close ch2. It is only safe to do this
    // after all the other goroutines have exited.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch2)
    }()
    for i := 0; i < sizeLetters; i++ {
        ch1 <- i // add i to the queue
    }
    close(ch1)
    if k, ok := <-ch2; ok && k != -1 { //when exist
        fmt.Println("X exist in position:", k)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("X doesn´t exist")
    }
}
```

It still has some data dependent issues (unless the `letters` array is guaranteed to not contain duplicates):

- Namely, if there is more than one `"x"` in the array, the goroutines will not all exit. That is, `main()` does not drain `ch2`.
- If there are as many as `threads` `"x"` values, then the code will deadlock in the top level `for` loop in `main()` since the writes to `ch1` will run out of unblocked goroutines to consume them.

  - If you know how many `"x"` values are possible in the `letters` array, you could make the `ch2` channel that deep: `ch2 := make(chan int, depth)`. This will allow all the goroutines to exit, but `ch2` will potentially still contain undrained data.

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually the "detectX" function represents a function that contains many validations, and when a validation detects an error, it reports it through the ch2 channel (in the example this is represented by ch2 <- j) and all it should stop at that moment, and the main function should return an answer, in the same way when when there is no "x", it would not really know how many "x" my array "letters" would have (errors in the real case). But you have clarified the picture for me more, thanks again.